# `LinearProgressIndicator` - "BoxConstraints forces an infinite width." error

Tags: flutter

My idea for a Flutter layout is to have two horizontally centered vertical `LinearProgressIndicator` widgets on top of each other, surrounded by 4 colored areas.

With two `LinearProgressIndicator` widgets, each wrapped in a `Expanded` widget, the error below occurs. Without the `LinearProgressIndicator` widget the error does not occur.

The error messages about `BoxConstraints` do not put me on the track of a solution to the problem.

### Error

```
======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
BoxConstraints forces an infinite width.

These invalid constraints were provided to RenderCustomPaint's layout() function by the following function, which probably computed the invalid constraints in question:
  RenderConstrainedBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:277:14)
The offending constraints were: BoxConstraints(w=Infinity, h=392.7)
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  LinearProgressIndicator file:///home/dpk/source/Android/demo_app/lib/main.dart:34:20
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      BoxConstraints.debugAssertIsValid.<anonymous closure>.throwError (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:517:9)
#1      BoxConstraints.debugAssertIsValid.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:559:21)
#2      BoxConstraints.debugAssertIsValid (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:565:6)
#3      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1679:24)
#4      RenderConstrainedBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:277:14)
...
The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderConstrainedBox#a9bbb relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...  parentData: <none> (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=Infinity, h=392.7)
...  size: MISSING
...  additionalConstraints: BoxConstraints(w=Infinity, 30.0<=h<=Infinity)
  child: RenderCustomPaint#91243 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
    parentData: <none>
    constraints: MISSING
    size: MISSING
RenderObject: RenderConstrainedBox#a9bbb relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
  parentData: <none> (can use size)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=Infinity, h=392.7)
  size: MISSING
  additionalConstraints: BoxConstraints(w=Infinity, 30.0<=h<=Infinity)
  child: RenderCustomPaint#91243 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
    parentData: <none>
    constraints: MISSING
    size: MISSING
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderConstrainedBox#a9bbb relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1930 pos 12: 'hasSize'


Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=2_bug.md

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  LinearProgressIndicator file:///home/dpk/source/Android/demo_app/lib/main.dart:34:20
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      RenderBox.size (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1930:12)
#3      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:117:21)
#4      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1779:7)
#5      RenderRotatedBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/rotated_box.dart:88:14)
#6      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1779:7)
...
The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#ba0b1 relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...  parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=Infinity, h=392.7)
...  size: MISSING
RenderObject: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#ba0b1 relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
  parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=Infinity, h=392.7)
  size: MISSING
...  child: RenderConstrainedBox#a9bbb relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...    parentData: <none> (can use size)
...    constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=Infinity, h=392.7)
...    size: MISSING
...    additionalConstraints: BoxConstraints(w=Infinity, 30.0<=h<=Infinity)
...    child: RenderCustomPaint#91243 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
...      parentData: <none>
...      constraints: MISSING
...      size: MISSING
====================================================================================================
```

### main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class UpperRow extends StatelessWidget {
  const UpperRow({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Container(
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: RotatedBox(
            quarterTurns: 3,
            child: LinearProgressIndicator(
              minHeight: 30,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

class LowerRow extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: RotatedBox(
            quarterTurns: 1,
            child: LinearProgressIndicator(
              minHeight: 30,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          color: Colors.red,
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          UpperRow(),
          LowerRow(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping `UpparRow` and `LowerRow` widget in Expanded will solve the issue but the each progressbar will take half of screen height. To solve this wrap `RotedBox` in container and provide the `alignment` value according to your need. Have a look in below code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage2(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage2 extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: UpperRow(),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: LowerRow(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class UpperRow extends StatelessWidget {
  const UpperRow({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Container(
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
        Expanded(
            child: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: RotatedBox(
            quarterTurns: 3,
            child: LinearProgressIndicator(
              minHeight: 30,
            ),
          ),
        )),
        Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

class LowerRow extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
        Expanded(
            child: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: RotatedBox(
            quarterTurns: 1,
            child: LinearProgressIndicator(
              minHeight: 30,
            ),
          ),
        )),
        Container(
          color: Colors.red,
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your changes fix the errors, but there appear no 4 colored areas (blue and red) next to the vertical `LinearProgressIndicator` widgets.

Comment: Do you wants to display these colors (blue and red) after `LinearProgressIndicator` ? If yes then add some height and width to `Container`

Comment: The vertical `LinearProgressIndicator` widgets should be centered horizontally and there should be colored areas to the left and right of them.